# How many possible starting moves are there in Abalone?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, abalone

I have not found a listing or reference to the initial number of moves.

I believe there are 44, but I'm not sure if this list is complete: https://github.com/void4/pyabalone/blob/master/allinitmoves.txt

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abalone_(board_game)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with 44.  Here's my break down:

Diagonal X2 (once for each diagonal direction):

- 6 moves with a single marble
- 5 in-line moves with 2 marbles
- 4 broadside moves with 2 marbles
- 3 in-line moves with 3 marbles
- 1 broadside move with 3 marbles

Horizontal

- 2 moves with a single marble
- 2 in-line moves with 2 marbles
- 2 in-line moves with 3 marbles

(6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 1) * 2 + (2 + 2 + 2) = 44.